# Rails associated model not being created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I got the following associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subscribers, :join_table => 'subscribers_users'
end

class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :devices, :join_table => 'subscribers_devices'
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subscribers, :join_table => 'subscribers_devices'
  has_many :device_attributes
end

class DeviceAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device
end
```

In user class, my create method looks like this:

```
def self.create(params)

  transaction do

    # create user
    user = User.new
    user.assign_attributes params

    # associate a device
    device = Device.build_from_params(params.dup)
    raise_if_invalid device
    subscriber.devices.push device

    # associate device_attributes to device
    params[:buttons].each do |b|
      # >>> problem here >>>
      device.device_attributes.build({:button_id => b[:button_id]})
    end

    user.save
  end

end
```

The problem occurs on the line that creates the device_attributes objects of the device. When this line is commented, my user is created properly along with its associated objects (a subscriber and a device). But when I un-comment it, my user has only a subscriber and that's it. It seems to stop and won't create any device along with the devce_attributes object!

There's no error in the console.. it's really strange to me, what's wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call `save` on each of the Device objects created in your loop. The `build` method instantiates a new object but doesn't actually save it to the database. See [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more details.

```
device.device_attributes.build({:button_id => b[:button_id]}).save()
```

or

```
current_device = device.device_attributes.build({:button_id => b[:button_id]})
current_device.save()
```

should do the trick.

Comment: But this should be automatic (children objects are saved when parent is saved) according to here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html, isn't it?

Comment: That might work if your call to User.save happened inside your loop. Since it's not called, each Device object goes out of scope and dies on each pass on your loop.